# Why installs graphs on Google Play look like sinusoid?

Tags: android, google-play

Many popular games on Google Play have "INSTALLS" graph shaped like a sinusoid:

[image]

This example was taken from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.halfbrick.fruitninjafree&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5oYWxmYnJpY2suZnJ1aXRuaW5qYWZyZWUiXQ..). Another examples: [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.halfbrick.jetpackjoyride&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmhhbGZicmljay5qZXRwYWNram95cmlkZSJd) and [there](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5yb3Zpby5hbmdyeWJpcmRzIl0.). You can easily find more.

The question is: why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a weekly cycle.  Some apps would be downloaded more often on weekdays, while others would be sought out more on weekends.

Some apps, as has already been noted, are more indifferent to weekends, and so do not exhibit a sinusoidal wave pattern of installs.  These are probably the ones in demand by those who take their work home, or who play games at work, or who sleep, shower and eat 24/7 in campus-like Internet startups.  Or else they are apps that are just work/play agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Not for all of them, look at [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5vdmVybG9vay5hbmRyb2lkLmZpbmciXQ..) and [Network Mapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.networkmapper&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwib3JnLnByb3dsLm5ldHdvcmttYXBwZXIiXQ..) to name some.

**Update:** Sorry, I see you notice the trend for *most* popular apps.

IDK why that is happening. I can't be related to time zones (i.e, assuming the major share of the market comes from the US and inferring that less people buy the app at night) as the graph is for the last 30 days.

Maybe something to do with how often Google indexes and updates this info?

Comment: 1) I can see sinusoidal trend in Network Mapper. 2) Google updates that graph every day.